# How to judge whether the meaning of two words is the same using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have some words just like this :

```py
['Java开发工程师', 'Java高级开发工程师', 'java开发工程师', 'JAVA开发工程师', '高级Java开发工程师', 'Java中级开发工程师', '高级java开发工程师', 'Java工程师', 'java工程师', 'JAVA工程师', 'Java架构师', '高级Java工程师', '高级java工程师', 'JAVA大数据开发工程师定岗生', '高级JAVA开发工程师', 'java+人工智能（AI）开发签约实习生', 'Java软件工程师', 'java软件工程师与人工智能开发委培', 'java高级开发工程师', 'Java开发实习生']
```

First of all , some words have the same meaning, such as :
java开发工程师 = Java工程师 = JAVA工程师， 
another example：
高级Java工程师 = Java高级工程师
now I want to find if they are same meaning ,then I can add them to a list.

Here is the code:

```py
cursor.execute("select title from job_java")
results = cursor.fetchall()
counter = dict()
for (item,) in results:
    counter[item] = counter.get(item, 0) + 1  # this codes
counter_sort = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda value: value[1], reverse=True)
```

what I expect is that 'java工程师' and 'JAVA工程师' counter add to the same dict index and this `高级Java工程师 = Java高级工程师`

I am intern to python ， can you give me advice? 
Because of that I can do this more specific.
[image: https://img.shownmmp.top/job.png]

Comment: Do you have a list of synonyms available somewhere?

Comment: In the beginning, I wrote synonyms words

Answer (score 0):

If your synonyms are in a dictionary:

```
synonyms = {"java开发工程师": "Java工程师", 
            "Java工程师": "JAVA工程师", 
            "高级Java工程师": "Java高级工程师"}
```

you can replace a word with its synonym if it has one with:

```
word = synonyms.get(word, word)
```

Comment: just like this  [('Java开发工程师', 64931), ('Java高级开发工程师', 25694), ('java开发工程师', 25010), ('JAVA开发工程师', 11669), ('高级Java开发工程师', 8379), ('Java中级开发工程师', 7355), ('高级java开发工程师', 6692), ('Java工程师', 5989), ('java工程师', 5751), ('JAVA工程师', 5560), ('Java架构师', 5208), ('高级Java工程师', 4659), ('高级java工程师', 4534), ('JAVA大数据开发工程师定岗生', 4489), ('高级JAVA开发工程师', 4348), ('java+人工智能（AI）开发签约实习生', 4289), ('Java软件工程师', 4109), ('java软件工程师与人工智能开发委培', 4064), ('java高级开发工程师', 3854), ('Java开发实习生', 3795)]

Comment: and I want to count java开发工程师 or other word

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking here. Did the above help with synonyms?